# Select a file on Android with given extension / MIME time

Tags: android, mime-types

I'm using the following code to open a .zip file from any available source (local storage, google drive, drop box etc):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
String mimetype = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("zip");

intent.setType(mimetype);

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a zip file");

if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
    startActivityForResult(chooser, 1);
```

That works well on my Nexus 5 (with Android 5.0) and on my Nexus 7 (Andorid 4.4.4). The standard Android dialog shows up allowing me to choose the zip file form google drive, drop box etc. Files not matching the requested extension are not selectable. Perfect!

But when I test it on Samsung Tab with Andoroid 4.4.2 it only shows the dropbox file chooser dialog... no google drive, no local storage, no file manager app...
Please consider that `mimetype` in the code above is equal to `application/zip`. If I change the code to `intent.setType("*/*");` it now shows all the options like in Nexus 5 (google drive, dropbox, local storage etc), however I can select any file, not only zip, and that's not what I want.

Comment: we have exactly the same problem as you with an app for a customer. But we try to open PDF files instead of ZIPs.

Have you already found a solution for it?

Comment: ...no in the end I gave up... I use intent.setType("\*/\*"); and then I check if the file chosen by the user is actually a zip (or pdf in your case). It's really annoying...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
intent.setType("application/zip|application/x-rar-compressed");
```